# Ruby + Prawn: How do I make text stick to bottom of page?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I have footer text that needs to stay at the bottom of the page: `"If you have any questions regarding your order, you may contact us"`. How would I position it absolutely?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way [from the docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn-layout/0.8.4/Prawn/Document#lazy_bounding_box-instance_method):

```
file = "lazy_bounding_boxes.pdf"
Prawn::Document.generate(file, :skip_page_creation => true) do                    
  point = [bounds.right-50, bounds.bottom + 25]
  page_counter = lazy_bounding_box(point, :width => 50) do   
    text "Page: #{page_count}"
  end 

  10.times do         
   start_new_page
    text "Some text"  
    page_counter.draw
  end
end
```